# Language translator not translating correctly

Tags: ibm-watson, language-translation

I am finding that IBM Watson language translator often doesn't translate correctly for certain languages. For example, in the case mentioned below you could see that it is not getting the translation done correctly.

```
languageTranslator.translate(
    {
      text: '凸版印刷株式会社',
      source: 'ja',
      target: 'en'
    })
    .then(response => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('error: ', err);
    });
//outputs
{
  "translations": [
    {
      "translation": "Convex Printed Stock Company"
    }
  ],
  "word_count": 4,
  "character_count": 8
}
// correct output: Toppan Printing Co., Ltd.
```

The languages identified have higher confidence to `zh` than `ja`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious and self explanatory. The text in Japanese is outputted as "Convex Printed Stock Company" and the correct translation should be "Toppan Printing Co., Ltd.". Not sure what additional details you need?

Comment: You could enter the same text at the tool https://www.ibm.com/demos/live/watson-language-translator/self-service/home and you'll get the same incorrect translation.